# Git show only heads of branches and tags

Tags: git

I'd like to have an overview of the tags and branches in my repository, including local and remote ones.

After searching for this with no luck I came up with the following grep (note that the first line is my usual `git log` alias):

```
alias gitlog='git log --color --graph --pretty=format:'\''%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'' --abbrev-commit'
gitlog --all | grep ' \-......('
```

That grep expression filters lines that contains a left bracket, which gives the desired result:

```
* 580c14b - (origin/sa, sa) 
* 1051cad - (HEAD -> mt, origin/bf, origin/de, bf, de) 
| * d19d6d6 - (origin/ms) 
| | * 6139779 - (origin/31)
| | | * 8005a54 - (origin/mr, mr) 
| | | * f1b6f37 - (origin/sp, sp) 
* 7a40270 - (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) 
* abeba99 - (tag: xx)
```

However, I'd like to get a similar result without resorting to `grep` over `git log` output.

How can I get a `git log` of commits that have a ref (branch, tag or stash) pointing to them?

Comment: Is `git branch -av` close to what you're looking for?

Comment: No, that's linear (but nice, I didn't know it :) ). I've just found it: `--simplify-by-decoration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph --simplify-by-decoration

* f586332 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge branch 'master' of github.com:dockerstuff/docker-jupyterhub-deploy
| * 86bba9c (origin/jupyter-isis-to-gispy-sharing, origin/erim23) fix base and notebook image references
| | * 26c9b4d (origin/simplify_settings) [wip] trying to understand why 500 error
| | | * c1774fa (refs/stash) WIP on simplify_settings: 5356738 [wip] organizing variables
| | |/  
| | * 5356738 (simplify_settings) [wip] organizing variables
| |/  
|/|   
* | a977d21 (origin/blue) Add start script to setup a 'gmap' user
* | 1c6c6a7 (bpsd_tmp) Change internal notebook-hub port, fix user volume permission args
|/  
* e974a8f Initial commit
```

Answer (score 1):

[git show-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch) — show branches and their commits.

`git show-branch --all --current` — show both remote-tracking branches and local branches, including the current branch.